# How can I make this code into more idiomatic pandas?

Tags: pandas, idioms

Kind of a broad question, but I am not sure how else to get pointers on how to improve this code.

I have a dataframe which has betting odds and game results, and I would like to compute the payout of investing in a certain team.

The code I have now works, but I feel like it skimps on much of what Pandas can do by just leaning on the `apply` method and dropping into Python.

Here's what the dataframe looks like:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
def compute_payout(odds, amount=1):
    if odds < 0:
        return amount/(-1.0 * odds/100.0)
    elif odds > 0:
        return amount/(100.0/odds)

def game_payout(row, team_name):
    if row['home_team'] == team_name:
        if row['home_score'] > row['away_score']:
            return compute_payout(row['home_odds'])
        else:
            return -1
    elif row['away_team'] == team_name:
        if row['away_score'] > row['home_score']:
            return compute_payout(row['away_odds'])
        else:
            return -1

payout = df.apply(lambda row: game_payout(row, team_name), axis=1)
```

Any suggestions are deeply appreciated!

Comment: data in text instead of image would help others to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with conditions chained by `&` for `bitwise AND` and `~` for invert boolean mask:

```
m11 = df['home_team'] == team_name
m21 = df['away_team'] == team_name

m12 = df['home_score'] > df['away_score']
m22 = df['home_score'] < df['away_score']

vals = [df['home_odds'].apply(compute_payout), -1, df['away_odds'].apply(compute_payout), -1]
payout = np.select([m11 & m12, m11 & ~m12, m21 & m22, m21 & ~m22], vals, default=np.nan)
```

Comment: This is cool! One question: how is it that `df['home_odds']` and `df['away_odds']` in the `vals` array will have the appropriate odds for the row of data that matched the select? (rather than just the entire series)

Comment: @JoshReback - it map first value from list of masks `[m11 & m12, m11 & ~m12, m21 & m22, m21 & ~m22]` to first value of vals, then second with second... And mask are chained together for all combination like you need in your code - e.g. `if row['home_team'] == team_name:
        if row['home_score'] > row['away_score']:` is convert to `m11 & m12` - or `(df['home_team'] == team_name) & (df['home_score'] > df['away_score'])`